# Microsoft Excel 2010 - postal code ranges

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to know how to get excel to understand postal code areas.

I have a starting postal code in for example A2, end of the range in B2 and price range for that area in B3, how can I get a formula to check on a postal code within the range and bring the right price range from B3 to complete the prices? Vlookup only understands the starting postal code and if it doesn't match 100 % with the postal code at hand, it just doesn't bring anything. What formula can I use for this sort of a problem?

Comment: Can you add the format of your postal codes? In some countries you have numbers and letters, and sometimes only numbers. This can influence the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have both kinds of postal codes. European postal codes with UK among them, so a part of them are with just numbers and UK on its own with both letters and numbers. Luckily they are in different excel documents, so I can edit the formula or use different ones to match the needs of a particular country.

Comment: Are you just looking for a formula or VBA?

Comment: Whatever works.

Comment: Please edit your question to add an example of your data, spreadsheet structure, and the lookup you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in VBA:

```
Public Sub AddCarriage()
  Dim intCOUNTER As Integer
  Dim intCOUNTER2 As Integer
  Dim intLASTROW As Integer
  Dim intPCNUMBER As Integer
  Dim strPCTEXT As String
  Dim intLENGTH As Integer
  Dim intPOS As Integer
  Dim strFIRST As String

' Get the last row of postcodes containing data
  intLASTROW = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

' Get the postcode for the delivery address
  strPCTEXT = Range("G1").Text

' Check if the postcode is all numeric (European?) or UK based
  If IsNumeric(Range("G1").Text) Then
    intPCNUMBER = Range("G1").Text
  Else
' Separate the numbers from the letters in a UK postcode
    intPOS = InStr(1, strPCTEXT, " ")
    If intPOS > 0 Then
      intLENGTH = intPOS - 1
      strFIRST = Left(Range("G1").Text, intPOS - 1)
      For intCOUNTER = 1 To intLENGTH
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strFIRST, intCOUNTER, 1)) Then
          strPCTEXT = Left(strFIRST, intCOUNTER - 1)
          intPCNUMBER = Mid(strFIRST, intCOUNTER, (intLENGTH - intCOUNTER) + 1)
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Else
      strPCTEXT = Range("G1").Text
    End If
  End If

  For intCOUNTER = 1 To intLASTROW
    If IsNumeric(Range("A" & intCOUNTER).Text) Then
      For intCOUNTER2 = Range("A" & intCOUNTER).Text To Range("B" & intCOUNTER).Text
        If intCOUNTER2 = intPCNUMBER Then Range("H1").Value = Range("E" & intCOUNTER).Value
      Next
    Else
      If Left(Range("A" & intCOUNTER).Text, Len(strPCTEXT)) = strPCTEXT Then
        For intCOUNTER2 = Mid(Range("A" & intCOUNTER).Text, Len(strPCTEXT) + 1, Len(intPCNUMBER)) To Mid(Range("B" & intCOUNTER).Text, Len(strPCTEXT) + 1, Len(intPCNUMBER))
          If intCOUNTER2 = intPCNUMBER Then Range("H1").Value = Range("E" & intCOUNTER).Text
        Next
      End If
    End If
  Next

' Row E contains the delivery cost for that postcode range
' Cell "H1" is the cell that the delivery cost is to be entered in to
End Sub
```

Obviously in my example the delivery cost is on the same sheet at the postcode being entered.  You'll need to add the relevant look ups to make this work with what you've got.